# A co-signed car for my husband isn't showing up on my Husband's credit. How can I improve both his and my credit records?

Tags: loans

I had to co-sign for my husband to get a vehicle before we got married. He's making all the payments, but it's on my credit. He can't get a loan for anything because he "doesn't have any credit", while my debt to income ratio looks bad because of the car. Is there any way to get the car on his credit?

Comment: If you co-signed - shouldn't it be on his credit already?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good shortcut here. You can try adding him to some of your older revolving accounts to try to boost his credit enough to refinance solo, but not all accounts will allow that.

Unless it's worth it for you to pay the higher interest rate that they will charge him without your name, the best bet is to try to make extra payments and pay it off ASAP.